# How to annotate text from one column onto a seaborn plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a seaborn line plot denoting one column, but would like to annotate text from another column just above the value shown in the line.  I can't seem to figure out the syntax.  The code below is a replica of my dataframe.  I would like to have the numbers from the 'flag' column annotated above the line of the group their observation corresponds to.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'group':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    ,'y':[100,200,300,400,500,650,780,810,932,1050]
    ,'flag':[1503, 601, 348, 193, 161, 197, 322, 237, 85, 38]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
g = sns.lineplot(x = 'group', y = 'y', data = df).set_title('Example Graph')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use [pandas.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) because it provides access to each `x` `y` value and the corresponding label.
- Use [matplotlib.pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) to add the text label.

  - `v[1][0]` is the x location and `v[1][1]` is the y location.
  - Change the placement of the label by adding or subtracting from the x or y value.

    - `x = v[1][0] - 0.2`
    - `y = v[1][1] + 14`
- See [Python Data Science Handbook: Text and Annotation](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.09-text-and-annotation.html) for additional options

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


d = {'group': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     'y': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 650, 780, 810, 932, 1050],
     'flag': [1503, 601, 348, 193, 161, 197, 322, 237, 85, 38]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
g = sns.lineplot(x = 'group', y = 'y', marker='.', data = df).set_title('Example Graph')

# add labels here
for v in df.iterrows():
    plt.text(v[1][0], v[1][1], f'{v[1][2]}')
```

[image]